# Swift - Array.first(where

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am having an issue with `userdataArray.first(where....)`.  Basically, I am aiming to pull out `userdata` for a message based on the `userId` to populate a cell.

The variable `userdata` contains an array. However when I try to configure the cell with `userdata?.name` the simulator gives an error.

What am I doing wrong? isn't `userdata` an array, or is it a nested array?

Code in `viewController`:

```
let userdata = userdataArray.first(where:{$0.userId == activity.userId})
print("Array filter test")
dump(userdata)

let image = UIImage(named: "profile_image")

cell.configureCell(profileImage: image!, profileName: "(userdata?.name)!", activityDate: "8 October", name: activity.name, distance: "8 km", sightings: activity.sightings, kills: activity.kills)
return cell
```

Output and error from Xcode:

```
Array filter test
▿ Optional(Shoota_MapKit.Userdata)
  ▿ some: Shoota_MapKit.Userdata #0
    - userId: "NhZZGwJQCGe2OGaNTwGvpPuQKNA2"
    - name: "Christian"
    - city: "Oslo"
    - country: "Norway"
    - profileImage: "profile_image"
```

Comment: Where's the error? I just see the log of your `userdataArray`.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka: You are right, I get the error when I use userdata?.name in the cell.configure. Xcode then get this error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"(userdata?.name)!"` is just a plain string, starting with an opening parenthesis. That's probably **not** what you wanted.

`"\(userdata?.name)!"` is a string using *string interpolation*. It will evaluate `(userdata?.name)!` If `userdata` is `nil`, then `userdata?.name` is `nil`, and the `!` will make it crash, which is intentional.

It recommend to use `if let ...` or `guard let ...` and use some alternative code if the item is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have user data:

```
guard let userdata = userdataArray.first(where:{$0.userId == activity.userId}),
      let image = UIImage(named: "profile_image") else {
           //no userdata
           return cell
}
cell.configureCell(profileImage: image, profileName: userdata.name, activityDate: "8 October", name: activity.name, distance: "8 km", sightings: activity.sightings, kills: activity.kills)
return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

@shallowThought: Thanks for the help. I ended up with the below, it seems to work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "feedCell") as? feedCell else {

      print("dequeueResuableCell return an else"); return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let activityDict = activityArray[indexPath.row]

    guard let userdata = userdataArray.first(where:{$0.userId == activityDict}) else {return cell}

     let image = UIImage(named: userdata.profileImage)

    cell.configureCell(profileImage: image!, profileName: userdata.name, activityDate: "8 October", name: activityDict.name, distance: "8 km", sightings: activityDict.sightings, kills: activityDict.kills)
    return cell

}
```

Comment: if your issue has been resolved, then accept shallowThought as accepted answer.

Comment: I recommend to `guard` or `if let` image` too, as every `!` potentially crashes.

Comment: @MandeepSingh If it were me, I'd suggest accepting gnasher729's instead, as it actually explains the reason for the problem, rather than just posting some code with no explanation.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, The user which asks the question if he understand the answer of shallow user, then that user will get the point not the other. Because I don't think so he understands the answer of gnasher729.

Comment: @MandeepSingh The problem I have with gnasher729's answer is that because it's just code, the OP does not have to understand it at all, but can just copy and paste it in.